# Nativescript Vue RadSideDrawer undefined

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-vue

I try to create start RadSideDrawer example https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=AZnAQ0

It works well with playground, but when I build it with

```
tns run android --bundle
```

I get an error

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.application/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

TypeError: Could not load view for: nativeradsidedrawer. TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/vendor.js, line: 59885, column: 6

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'getViewClass', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/vendor.js', line: 63313, column: 11
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Just took your playground sample and ran the following commands in my local  - tns build android --bundle and tns run android --bundle. The app is getting loaded properly. I tested it with API 25. What is the API level you are using ?

Comment: Did you try downloading the playground sample directly and running it on local machine? Just to make sure you run the same configuration locally too.

Comment: I have project with 10 pages. Now I whant add sidebar in main page but can't. I create page like in playground example and get that error

Comment: Downloaded project work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to update tns

```
tns update next
```

Answer (score 0):

First we need to build the app using below command

tns build android --bundle

Once build is successful we have to run below command

tns run android --bundle

[image: Android API 25 Emulator]

Comment: Downloaded project work well. I have project with 10 pages. Now I whant add sidebar in main page but can't. I create page like in playground example and get that error